# 跟到: 方言? Or what?

Tags: topolect, word

Is the word 跟到, as in 我们跟到就走, part of MSM? If not, what topolect is it from? Is there any documentation on it? (Dictionary entries, etc.)

In case it's not clear the meaning of 跟到 is pretty much the same as 马上 here - and does not mean follow.

edit: I've heard it used frequently in the 四川 area

Comment: What does MSM stand for?

Comment: Modern Standard Mandarin

Comment: even I'm a Chinese native speaker, I also don't know what's this means,

Comment: Can you give more context? Where did you find this phrase, or who did you hear utter it?

Comment: @congusbongus updated my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well apparently I got the characters wrong as it should be “跟倒”...

1. It is not part of MSM.
2. It's from 四川话
3. Documentation:

from "四川方言词典":

[image: 四川方言词典]

from "成都方言词典":

[image: 成都方言词典]

Answer (score 3):

Well, "我们跟到就走" is not widely used and seems wired. Maybe you should provide more context.

"跟到" means "arrive" or "as soon as I/we finish doing something". I would like to translate "我们跟到就走" into "We will leave here as soon as I/we finish doing something/dressing/packaging/etc".

Update to answer more precisely: it's not the Modern Standard Mandarin, and it seems rarely used.

Comment: Yeah....not what I was asking for at all

Comment: I said "... is not widely used and seems wired", so the sentence is not Modern Standard Mandarin.

Comment: Well that still only answers one of my three questions

Answer (score 2):

In Sichuan, `跟到` means `sooner` - indicating that something is gonna happen soon or sooner.